# d3.js Box Plot Positioning Issue with box.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, boxplot

I'm trying to implement box plots as part of a data visualization interface that uses d3 and AngularJS. I'm working with this box plot package: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4061502.

However, I can't figure out which part of the sample code controls the positioning of the box plots. In the example, the five box plots are arranged sequentially. When I try to generate my plots, they all appear on top of each other.

[image]

Here is the code that I'm using to generate the box plots:

```
            boxplots = svg.selectAll("svg")
                .data(boxPlotData)
                .enter().append("svg")
                .attr("class", "box")
                .attr("width", boxWidth + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", boxHeight + margin.bottom + margin.top)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
                .call(chart);
```

Here's the code for how my svg canvas is created. This is done in an angular directive:

```
template:"<svg width='825' height='600'></svg>",
    link: function($scope, elem){

        var d3 = $window.d3;
        var rawSvg=elem.find('svg'); // this is the svg created in the template

        var width = rawSvg[0].attributes[0].value;
        var height = rawSvg[0].attributes[1].value;

        var svg = d3.select(rawSvg[0]);
```

Edit: not perfect yet but getting there:

[image]

Comment: What's the parent element of the `<svg>` elements you create? Note that in the example the parent is an HTML element and not an SVG element. So basically they create a separate image for each box, which automatically get placed beside each other.

Comment: I updated my original post with the code that creates my SVG canvas. Since I have an SVG element as the parent for the box plots, it seems that they're both just defaulting to (0, 0) for their starting location. I'm assuming I need to translate them to the right location? Where does that code go? They're both being created at once so I'm not sure how to give them different translate coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is an ordinal scale to position the svg-elements for the boxes within the parent svg. Assuming `width` represents the width of your parent svg element and `data` is an array of your data elements, you can use this to create the scale:

```
const x = d3.scaleBand()
              .range( [0, width] )
              .domain( data.map( (el,i) => i ) );
```

Within the svg creation you can now use

```
boxplots = svg.selectAll("svg")
                .data(boxPlotData)
                .enter().append("svg")
                .attr( "x", (d,i) => x(i) ) // this is added
                .attr("class", "box")
                .attr("width", boxWidth + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", boxHeight + margin.bottom + margin.top)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
               .call(chart);
```

PS: This assumes you use v4 of d3js. The syntax in v3 for the scale is different.

PPS: I currently can not test the code, but it should work like described.

Comment: I added in your code. Needs some tweaking--the width of each boxplot is defined by a variable (boxWidth, should be 80 pixels right now) so they need to shift over by at least that much. I'm sure I can get it if I play around with it for a bit.

Comment: Followup question: can I use scaleBand to create two different groups of boxplots? Ultimately, I need four plots, two on each side of the screen.

Comment: i'll have another run at it tomorrow. I currently do not have the time.

Comment: Weirdly, setting the maximum on the domain to about 10000 spaces the box plots out properly. Setting the x attribute allows for a scalar value to be added. Oddly enough, setting that added value to width/2 places the box plots at about 3/4 of the way across the SVG rather than half way. Setting the offset to 300 pixels seems to do the trick. I wonder why that is

Comment: I created a small fiddle for my code at https://jsfiddle.net/cLeqx2eh/1/ . It does not yet include the actual boxplots, but instead a line in the middle of each band. Seems to work just fine.

Comment: Regarding your other question: I'm not sure I'm getting you right, but I think the easiest way would be to split the input data and just call the boxplot creation twice (once for each part of the input data). This is probably much easier then having d3 try to do this.